# Google Cloud Storage JSON API returns bad request for listing project buckets though API explorer works for the same

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to list Google Cloud Buckets for my Google Cloud project from Unity 2018 (.Net core 2.0 C# ).
Since client librariy is not supported from unity, I need to do it from JSON APIs only.

From API explorer I tried it and it works

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=my_project&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Since API explorer does not allow directly entering API key there, I did Oauth. Except for oauth, I just used the same URL string.

But I get bad request while it worked from API explorer.

My code is here below

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?  project=my_project&key=" + "=" + m_APIKey);

        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Method = "GET";


       var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.Log(result.ToString());
        }
```

But I get bad request error:

```
WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
```

Please suggest what could be going wrong here.

Thanks a lot.
Regards

Comment: It looks like you have some superfluous spaces in your URL. That could be an issue?

Comment: Can you let us know if the comment by Brandon Yarbrough is the solution to your answer? I have also noticed that you added another `+ "=" +` before inserting the API key, while you already have a `=` symbol.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is space. And also there was extra "=".  Thanks for the response!